# Initialise StandardScaler from scaling parameters

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have previously fitted data and I have saved the `scaler.mean_` and `scaler.var_` arrays. I know that I can pickle the whole `StandardScaler()` object and use it later to transform new data.

However, I need to know if I can generate the `StandardScaler()` object again from the saved arrays of mean and variance, something like:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.mean_ = mean_array
scaler.var_ = var_array
new_data = scaler.transform(new_data)
```

Obviously, the new data is of the same format (number of features). I can do it manually, but I was hoping that I can load the scaling parameters again to the object and use it. When I run the code above, the error is:

> **NotFittedError**: This StandardScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call
>   'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.

I tried also initialising with `scaler = StandardScaler(copy=False)`, but I had the same result.

Any suggestions how this might work?

Comment: Not sure if it'll work, but - try fitting it on something, and then overriding `.var_` and `.mean_`?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin Good suggestion, although a bit hacky. There are a lot of errors here and there with array shapes, so not really sure what is happening. I was hoping for a normal way to load the `var_` and `mean_` arrays...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the solution. I was not setting all three attributes: `scale_`, `mean_` and `var_` (I was setting only the last two).

So, as a continuation of Itamar's example, this code works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': [13,14,15],'b':[-1,1,2]}).astype(float)
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(df)
print(scaler.scale_, scaler.mean_, scaler.var_)

df2 = df.copy(deep=True)
df2[df.columns] = scaler.transform(df)
print(df2)

# Initialise completely the scaler object
scaler = StandardScaler()

# Using the standard deviation, mean and variance results from above.
scaler.scale_ = np.array([0.81649658, 1.24721913])
scaler.mean_ = np.array([14.0, 0.66666667])
scaler.var_ = np.array([0.66666667, 1.55555556])

df3 = df.copy(deep=True)
df3[df.columns] = scaler.transform(df)
print(df3)
```

Prints:

```
[ 0.81649658  1.24721913] [ 14.           0.66666667] [ 0.66666667  1.55555556]

          a         b
0 -1.224745 -1.336306
1  0.000000  0.267261
2  1.224745  1.069045

          a         b
0 -1.224745 -1.336306
1  0.000000  0.267261
2  1.224745  1.069045
```

Which is the expected same result. The issue with the `NotFittedError` was rising because I was only setting the `mean_` and `var_`, and not the `scale_`, as I was saving just those two. In my case I can reproduce the latter with:

`scaler.scale_ = np.sqrt(scaler.var_)`, after setting the `scaler.var_` first of course.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on my comment - you can indeed fit and then override, no problem with shapes. Also, the scaling parameters are `.scale_` and `.mean_`, not '.var_`and '.mean_`. 
 As you can see, it is indeed hacky and not pretty, but it works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': [13,14,15],'b':[-1,1,2]}).astype(float)
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(df)
print(scaler.scale_, scaler.mean_, scaler.var_)

df2 = df.copy(deep=True)
df2[df.columns] = scaler.transform(df)
print(df2)

scaler.scale_ = [1,1]
df3 = df.copy(deep=True)
df3[df.columns] = scaler.transform(df)

print(df3)

[0.81649658 1.24721913] [14.          0.66666667] [0.66666667 1.55555556]

      a         b
0 -1.224745 -1.336306
1  0.000000  0.267261
2  1.224745  1.069045

    a         b
0 -1.0 -1.666667
1  0.0  0.333333
2  1.0  1.333333
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working as you pointed out. I think I was trying to do this with much frustration and I was using a vector instead of the right shape array. I am only doing this for individual inputs, so I think I will use the expression `X = (X-saved_mean)/saved_std`, instead of pre-fitting twice.